# Use postman to send data to a apigee proxy

Tags: apigee

I want to post the following json data to apigee proxy.I created a apigee proxy with no target servers.
I copy the url from overview section in apigee and copied it into url in postman.I changed the verb in postman to Post.
      I used the following apigee community post.

```
  https://community.apigee.com/questions/54530/creating-an-api-proxy-for- 
  post-request.html

  The data I post is { "age":30 }
```

When i click on the url it gives me response 200 .But in trace we can see the post action. I change postman header into Json(application/json)

But how do I check the data in my proxy?Next time I click on the url  in overview section in apigee it shows me no data.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. could you please post some screen shots and explain it?

Comment: @Naveen Nelamali Please see this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54340796/how-do-i-send-data-from-1-api-to-another-api-using-apigee

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on the individual steps in the Trace tool. There you can see the request payload that you're seeking.