# How do I send data from 1 api to another api using apigee

Tags: redirect, apigee

I am recently started using  apigee proxy.Please do not block me.
I am using postman to post data into proxy.
I have assigned a extract policy to extract some values from the json data like
speed,latitude, longitude etc.
Then I have used a assign policy to convert speed into gpsspeed etc as per client requirement.
After that i use javascript policy to output if speed is higher > 50 then high or low.
I am giving an example of the data.
Now i want to forward the resultant data to another api.Maybe anything apigee offers for testing purpose.I want to see the data in the resultant api.
I used service call out policy to send data to another url.
I am attaching the policy.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <ServiceCallout name="ServiceCallout-GeocodingRequest1">
 <DisplayName>Inline request message</DisplayName>
 <Request variable="callAnotherService">
    <Set>
        <Payload contentType="application/json">
          {response.content} // reading data from javascript policy
        </Payload>
    </Set>
</Request>
<Response>CalloutResponse</Response>
<Timeout>30000</Timeout>
<HTTPTargetConnection>
    <URL>http://httpbin.org/anything</URL>
</HTTPTargetConnection>
```

[image: trace call]
I have attached a javascript policy before it.
I am attaching the policy.

```
 var content = context.getVariable("response.content") //read the response
  content = JSON.parse(content); //parse into an object
  if (content.speed > 50) { //apply the condition
  content.speed = "high";
   }
  else {
  content.speed = "low";
  }
  context.setVariable("response.content", JSON.stringify(content)); //set it 
  back on the response
```

Can anyone help me how can i forward the data to another api? Is my procedure right?Is the procedure to extract variables from java script policy right?Please guide me.

Comment: Are you sure that the object "response.content" in your javascript policy is not empty after you set the value back to it

Comment: Its not empty..

Answer (score 1):

Okay, if you are sure that value after setVarible is not empty, So try code below.

**Note:** In your JavaScript Policy I have changed the variable name after set the value back to it (for not confusing).

```
var content = context.getVariable("response.content") //read the response
content = JSON.parse(content); //parse into an object
if(content.speed > 50){ 
    content.speed = "high";
}
else{
    content.speed = "low";
}
context.setVariable("serviceCalloutRequest", JSON.stringify(content)); //I have changed from "response.content" to "serviceCalloutRequest"
```

And try this in Service Callout Policy:

```
<Request clearPayload="true" variable="callAnotherService">
    <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>false</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
    <Set>       
        <Payload variablePrefix="@" variableSuffix="#">@serviceCalloutRequest#</Payload>
        <Verb>POST</Verb>
    </Set>
</Request>
```

Use **variablePrefix** and **variableSuffix** to reference the value that you have assign in your javascript policy, In this case I refer from "serviceCalloutRequest".